# multi value return SP

Tags: stored-procedures

How can you return multi values from one Stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the following way (These relate to SQL Server, the syntax may be different with other databases.)

1. Use multiple OUTPUT parameters
   See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108.aspx
2. Have multiple select statements in a stored procedure.
3. Use return value's
   See: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Stored_Procedures_-_Output_Parameters_%26_Return_Values